# How do i span fo:table-cell from one named column to another?

Tags: xml, xslt, cell, xsl-fo

I am transforming this xml table to pdf using xslt. The entry/@namest identifies where the span starts and entry/@nameend identifies where the span should end.

I have spanned cells before with numeric @colname values but this one stumps me. Please help.

This is my source xml:

```
<table>
    <title>table title</title>
    <tgroup cols="5" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
        <colspec colname="colspec0" colwidth="557*"/>
        <colspec colname="colspec2" colwidth="823*"/>
        <colspec colname="colspec1" colwidth="702*"/>
        <colspec colname="col1" colwidth="4452*"/>
        <colspec colname="col2" colwidth="4646*"/>
        <thead>
        <row>
            <entry namest="colspec0" nameend="col1" valign="middle" align="center">
                    <para>this cell should span to 4th column</para>
            </entry>
            <entry valign="middle" align="center">
                <para>non span cell</para>
            </entry>
        </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

This is a snippet of my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="colspec">
<fo:table-column>
    <xsl:attribute name="column-number"><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::colspec + 1)"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="column-width"><xsl:value-of select="$mm-to-in"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:table-column>        
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="entry"> 
<fo:table-cell empty-cells="show" xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell.padding"> 
    <xsl:if test="@namest and @nameend">
        <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
            <xsl:value-of select="(@nameend - @namest) + 1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:block> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(text()) &lt; 1">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>&#160;
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with your approach? How does it fail / do you get any error messages? Also, people would be more willing to help if you provided a _full_ example - complete source file and XSLT stylesheet that can be tested.

Comment: If you are working with CALS tables, you may ask this (simplified) question but ned a full understanding of all the things possible. Especially cosidering you can have spanned rows and columns. Take a look here: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7450.html#d10399e682

Comment: @Mathias - My approach works well when the '@namest' and '@nameend' values are numeric. However in this case they are textual (ref number-column-spanned). I ended up solving this issue by adding a new attribute ('@colnum') to the colspec element. I don't like adding content to the source, but it works. 
I appreciate the feedback from you both.